# how to navigate to either of two pages using ternary condition in flutter using firebase database

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

[image: here is my firebase database]

hey I am new to flutter and searched a lot in google and youtube for the answer but couldn't. I am building a online home bakery store , so required to create 'Users' sub-collections seller and customer

```
     final pages = [
const HomepageCustomer(),
const Favoritepage(),
const Cartpage (),
const Profielpage(),
];
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return SafeArea(
  child: Scaffold(
    body: pages[pageIndex],
```

added a variable pages to navigate between pages using bottom navigation bar, and called it in body.
Here the only possible way is the when the user sign in as a seller or customer(that ain't matter),the page display only customer's page.

I just wanted to use ternary condition to navigate between them(customer page or seller page). Wanted to navigate to customer page if there customer clicks on customer(*firebase database picture), if that's a seller navigate to seller home page.

Comment: You created any method for checking current user is customer or seller..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to check current user is this customer or seller and store in varibale or any models.

Create List for customers pages

```
 final customerPages = [
const HomepageCustomer(),
const Favoritepage(),
const Cartpage (),
const Profielpage(),
];
```

Create List for Seller Pages

```
 final sellerPages = [
const HomepageCustomer(),
const Favoritepage(),
const Cartpage (),
const Profielpage(),
];
```

Use in widget build

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return SafeArea(
  child: Scaffold(
    body: //(Put your current user check method with return bool) ? customerPages[pageIndex] : sellerPages[pageIndex],
```

Comment: would you help me with the body's ternary condition ? i don't know to implement your condition .=> (Put your current user check method with return bool) ? customerPages[pageIndex] : sellerPages[pageIndex],

Comment: Yes sure, Please share the code of checking current user is seller or customer.